# How do I get polymorphic tests working with cucumber-jvm and guice?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, guice, cucumber-jvm

I've a simple web UI in JSF2 in order to demonstrate how to use cucumber as a BDD framework to my team. The app is super simple - you type in a sum, it gives you the answer. Right now we're only implementing positive integers - so its effectively just echo-ing whats in the sum box.

I'm using the pages pattern, so I have a set of features defined, which hit a set of steps, which call a Home interface. I'd like to be able to reuse the features to test different levels of the application by injecting a different implementation of the Home interface depending on which test is being run. For example, one implementation might spin up selenium and use a WebDriver to drive the UI, another implementation might call a java object directly.

I have two test classes:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "classpath:features", glue=<somepackage>)
public class SeleniumTest {

}
```

and

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "classpath:features", glue=<somepackage>)
public class JavaTest {

}
```

I've tried using a module with this configure method:

```
protected void configure() {    
    install(new PrivateModule() {
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            bind(Home.class).to(SeleniumHome.class);
            expose(SeleniumTest.class);
        }
    });
    install(new PrivateModule() {
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            bind(Home.class).to(JavaHome.class);
            expose(JavaTest.class);
        }
    });
}
```

But this gives me

```
initializationError(package.SeleniumTest): Failed to instantiate public cucumber.runtime.java.JavaBackend(cucumber.runtime.io.ResourceLoader) with [cucumber.runtime.io.MultiLoader@790da477]
initializationError(package.HomeTest): Failed to instantiate public cucumber.runtime.java.JavaBackend(cucumber.runtime.io.ResourceLoader) with [cucumber.runtime.io.MultiLoader@790da477]
```

If I change the module to bind directly, without the PrivateModule, then (as you'd expect) both tests execute exactly the same steps twice - but it does bind and it does execute:

```
protected void configure() {    
    bind(Home.class).to(SeleniumHome.class);
}
```

works, as does:

```
protected void configure() {    
    bind(Home.class).to(JavaHome.class);
}
```

For completeness, my feature file looks like:

```
Feature: Literals story

Narrative:
In order to start to build up more complex expressions
As a parser user
I want to be able to use numbers directly in my expression string

Scenario:  This is a selection of positive literals we can test with
    Given I visit the webpage
    When I submit the expression 5
    Then the result should be 5

    When I submit the expression 6
    Then the result should be 6
```

and my steps file looks like:

```
public class ParserSteps {

    private Home home;

    @Inject
    public ParserStepsImpl(Home home) {
        this.home = home;
    }

    @Given("I visit the webpage")
    public void theUserVisitsTheWebpage() {
        home.open();
    }

    @When("I submit the expression (.*)")
    public void theySubmitTheExpression(String value) {
        home.calculate(value);
    }

    @Then("the result should be (-?\\d+)")
    public void theResultShouldBe(Double value) {
        assertEquals(true, home.checkResult(value));
    }

}
```

Comment: "depending on which test is run". Don't test with Guice. You should be testing your real code, not your injections. If needed, use mocks.

Comment: You misunderstand - i'm not testing guice. What I'd like to do is effectively implement the steps in two ways, so given a feature with a specified expression, when the `JavaTest` is run, then `JavaHome` is injected and the `Parser.calculate(String expression)` method is called directly. When `SeleniumTest` is run then `SeleniumHome` is injected and a browser would be launched and the expression is typed into the text box. In the second case I may have the `Parser` object mocked - so I'm definitely testing my code and not guice - I'm just reusing the BDD acceptance criteria in both scenarios.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cucumber with Guice - multiple guice injector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35315963/cucumber-with-guice-multiple-guice-injector)